# How do I monitor specific tasks with OmniThreadLibrary

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I want to use the OmniThreadLibrary's default thread Pool, i.e. not create my own local ones.

I have a method ValidateInvoiceFile.  An invoice file is simply a list of invoice objects which is self contained.

ValidateInvoiceFile is called in my Service.  User 1 validates File 1 and user 2 validates File 2 - this would occur in 2 totally independent calls

For example

User 1 - File 1 - Invoice 1, Invoice 2, Invoice 3

User 2 - File 2 - Invoice 34231, Invoice 31235

Each invoice is going to be validated in its own task.  So in this case I would have 5 tasks.

I need my ValidateInvoiceFiles procedure to wait until all of the tasks if created have been finished.  NOT all tasks.  In a lot of cases people want to wait until all tasks have been completed, but this is not the case here.

The ValidateInvoices call for File 1 has no interest in the tasks for File 2 so I dont want it to wait for them

How would I do this using the OmniThreadLibrary for Delphi

I was thinking about the OnThreadTerminated event, but I am not sure how to make this only care about the tasks added during a specific call.

```
procedure ValidateInvoiceFile(const objInvoices: TInvoices)
begin
  try
    objThreadPool := CreateThreadPool('Connection pool');
    objThreadPool.MaxExecuting := 2 * System.CPUCount;

    nStart := 0;
    nEnd := 49;

    while nStart <= objInvoices.Count - 1 do
    begin
      for InvoiceIndex := nStart to nEnd do
      begin
        if InvoiceIndex > objInvoices.Count - 1 then
          Break;

        objInvoice := objInvoices[InvoiceIndex];

        objValidationData := TValidationData.Create(FConnection, FAllInvoices, FAllInvoices[InvoiceIndex]);
        //I fill objValidationData with information to be given to the task

        CreateTask(
          procedure(const task: IOmniTask)
          var
            objLocalInvoice: TInvoice;
            ValidatorIndex: Integer;
            objValidator:   TInvValidator;
            objUtilities:   TUtilities;
            objValidationData: TValidationData;
            nLocalInvoiceIndex: Integer;
            nValidatorIndex: Integer;
          begin
            nLocalInvoiceIndex := Task.Param['InvoiceIndex'].AsInteger;
            objValidationData := TValidationData(Task.Param['objValidationData'].AsObject);
            try
               //Do my work here
            finally
              FreeAndNil(objValidationData);
            end;
          end
          )
          .SetParameter('InvoiceIndex', InvoiceIndex)
          .SetParameter('objValidationData', TObject(objValidationData))
          .Unobserved
          .Schedule(objThreadPool);
      end;

      /**** This is the part I dont know how to change*****/
      while objThreadPool.CountExecuting + objThreadPool.CountQueued > 0 do
        Self := Self;

        Inc(nStart, 50);
        Inc(nEnd, 50);
     end;
  finally
    objThreadPool := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Which Delphi are you using? There are high-level abstractions that would help you here if you are using at least Delphi 2009.

Comment: I am using Delphi XE 5

Comment: Am I right in thinking that local thread pools in my situation are not a good idea? There could any number of files being validated at the same time.  On a normal day we have around 100 instances of the system in use and cannot predict what the users are going to do!  They want to be able to validate multiple files at the same time.  I think if I use local pools I could end up having too many threads in use

Comment: You don't need a local thread pool. You just need a better abstraction.

Comment: If I understand correctly ValidateInvoiceFile is started (potentially) at the same time for multiple users. Each ValidateInvoiceFile would like to process its invoices in parallel (as much as possible). Each ValidateInvoiceFile would wait for all invoices to be processed and would then return.

If so, you just need Parallel.For.

Comment: ok I am very new to this! I do like this library :)  I am a bit concerned how I get access violations when running the same applications on different machines, but hopefully any help I can get here may lead to a better approach which solves these at the same time!  Ironically, the access violations dont occur inside XP, but seem to be when run on a 64 bit machine/a machine with ability to run more threads

Comment: Yes,  Every call is totally independant.  Each call is executed within in its own session where there is a direct connection between the server and the client.  So I wouldnt need to deal with CreateTask etc.  I will see if I can work that out!  Wheres the best place to a get a pointer from for how to do this using Parallel.For please?

Comment: Sorry I was typing this as you put your answer on!

Comment: You can learn more here: https://leanpub.com/omnithreadlibrary, http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php, http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com/tutorials.htm

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to this should work (if I understand the problem correctly):

```
uses   
  OtlCommon,   
  OtlParallel;

GlobalParallelPool.MaxExecuting := Environment.System.Affinity.Count * 2;

procedure ValidateInvoiceFile(const objInvoices: TInvoices);
begin   
  Parallel.ForEach(0, objInvoices.Count - 1)
    .Execute(
      procedure(const invoiceIndex: integer)
      begin
        //validate objInvoices[invoiceIndex]
      end); 
end;
```

Comment: ok thanks is 2 * Environment.System.Affinity.Count just a better way than doing 2 * System.CPUCount?

Comment: That's OmniThreadLibrary way of saying the same thing. Older Delphis didn't provide the CPUCount so I wrote my own functions.

Comment: ok cool.  If this is being called by 2 users on machine with 8 cores does this mean there could be 16 threads running or would it be 8?  I.e. does the max threads apply to each call or to the pool behind the scenes?

Comment: Actually, NumTasks means that that much threads are created. They are all scheduled to the GlobalParallelPool pool which runs unlimited number of threads by default.

In your case it would be better to limit the GlobalParallelPool to System.CPUCount*2 and to leave each Parallel.ForEach with default settings. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  If I have 2 users validating 2 seperate files will this mean that the process will be slower?  I am trying to get into a position where each file being validated is independant.  Using Parallels.ForEach makes sense, but I am worried about other users being slowed down.  Without threading each file has its own session so processing starts immediatley

Comment: I don't know, test it out.